# Assign datetime range to variable using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to split a df by datetime. The df is indexed on the datetime variable. Essentially, I can do:

```
first = df['2020-04-09':'2020-04-21']
second  = df['2020-04-22':'2020-05-08']
```

and that yields my desired result of 2 dfs, each with their respective datetime range's worth of data.

However, I'd like a way to allow for easier editing at the top of the script by assigning the datetime ranges to local variables. Ideally something like this:

```
first_dates = '2020-04-09':'2020-04-21'
second_dates = '2020-04-22':'2020-05-08'
```

Such that later on I'm able to use something like:

```
first = df[first_dates]
second = df[second_dates]
```

and yield the same result of 2 dfs with their respective date ranges worth of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want

```
# edit this
date_str = '2020-04-21'

# no need to edit this
date = pd.to_datetime(date_str, utc=True)


first = df[:date]
second = df[date+pd.to_timedelta('1D'):]
```

Comment: Almost - except your code yields TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects, which wasn't previously an issue

Comment: Can you add a printout of`df.index`?

Comment: `DatetimeIndex(['2020-04-09 10:04:35+00:00', '2020-04-10 03:29:17+00:00',
               '2020-04-10 07:16:42+00:00', '2020-04-10 13:56:41+00:00',
               '2020-04-10 14:50:00+00:00', '2020-04-10 22:15:12+00:00',
                ...
               '2020-05-07 13:29:12+00:00', '2020-05-07 17:30:00+00:00',
               '2020-05-08 00:36:18+00:00', '2020-05-08 18:52:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='date', freq=None)`

Answer (score -1):

Using datetime, you could use mask comparison maybe?
like:

```
mask1 = df.index <= dt.date(2020,4,21)
mask2 = df.index > dt.date(2020,4,21)

df1 = df.loc[mask1]
df2 = df.loc[mask2]
```